# Call onclick jQuery function once

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-events

How can I execute this function only one time? I tried bind or unbind but it doesn't work

```
<uib-tab-heading onclick="myFunction()"><i class="fa fa-keyboard-o"></i> Typing Test </uib-tab-heading>
```

```
function myFunction() {
    alert("hit");   
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this below :

```
Use this flag in your $document.ready scope (global scope)

var flag = false

if(!flag){

    function myFunction() {
        flag = true;
        alert("hit");   
    }

}
```

Comment: You want the flag *inside* function as it's being called from `onclick=` which won't find that function inside doc.ready or an `if`